# ValueEventListener never triggered

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `FragmenPageAdpater` class where I am trying to get info about the current user so that I can load the right fragment for this specific user.

The `ValueEventListener` never gets triggered and it keeps skipping the body part.

```
public SessionListAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseDatabase myData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference dataUser = myData.getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    dataUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("Tutor")) //if(readType.equals("Tutor"))  if user is a Tutor
                user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Tutor.class);
            else
                user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the necessary portion of my database structure.

[image]

Comment: where are you declaring the user object ?

Comment: Above it as a public variable

Comment: and what its type Student or Tutor ?

Comment: I have a User class which is a parent of type Student and Tutor

Comment: try to debug your code and check if there dataSnapshot exits. your Code is ok. also make sure you are getting the right object from data snapshot to cast

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` like the following. I am referring to this [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once).

```
dataUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if(dataSnapshot.child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("Tutor"))
          user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Tutor.class);
      else
          user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Hope that helps!